# Regular Expression to catch email encoded attachments string

Tags: regex

I would like to write a regular expression that catch Encoded Words parts from email MIME message string (eml). for example, this is part of email:

```
<div dir=3D"ltr"><br clear=3D"all"><div><div dir=3D"ltr"><div style=3D"dire=
ction:rtl">-------------</div><div style=3D"direction:rtl">=D7=91=D7=91=D7=
=A8=D7=9B=D7=94,</div><div style=3D"direction:rtl">=D7=90=D7=91=D7=99=D7=A2=
=D7=93 =D7=9B=D7=94=D7=9F</div></div></div>
</div>

--20cf3003bc2e044e980500f755dc--
--20cf3003bc2e044e9d0500f755de
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII; name="EhudBanay.txt"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="EhudBanay.txt"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
X-Attachment-Id: f_hz0z4us30
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--20cf3003bc2e044e9d0500f755de--
```

i would like to catch only this part:

```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```

I didn't manage to do it with regular expression so i tried to use the following line which always start with "--" and ends with "--". notice that before the wanted part there is always an empty line.
I tried: "(\s).*(--)$" but it returns only the following line.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're trying to parse multipart/mixed email. There are libraries in most languages to do this already. If you want to write your own I'd suggest following [the structure of a multipart message](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME).

- Find the boundary defined in the content-type header
- Split the message into parts delimited by the boundary (prefixed by --).
- For each part seek to the first instance of two consecutive line breaks that denote the end of the headers.

While regular expressions might be helpful for some part of this. I'm not sure its the right tool to parse a structured message.

Comment: You are right. I used JavaMail library for parsing email messages (Mime format, eml files). Now i want to check another thing and need to get the encoded words section. i succeed with: 
(?<=\\r\\n\\r\\n)(.+\\r\\n)+(?=--)
but it sometimes end with: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
\n\s*\n\K(?:[^-]{2})*.?(?=\n--)
```

[**Online demo**](https://regex101.com/r/bO8oZ2/1)

Comment: for some reason you regex is not working on my java.